# prefix matching in python

Tags: python

I have a string like:

```
" This is such an nice artwork"
```

and I have a tag_list `["art","paint"]`

Basically, I want to write a function which accepts this string and taglist as inputs
and returns me the word "artwork" as artwork contains the word art which is in taglist.

How do i do this most efficiently?

I want this to be efficient in terms of speed

```
 def prefix_match(string, taglist):
        # do something here
     return word_in string
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def prefix_match(sentence, taglist):
    taglist = tuple(taglist)
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.startswith(taglist):
            return word
```

This works because [`str.startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) can accept a tuple of prefixes as an argument.

Note that I renamed `string` to `sentence` so there isn't any ambiguity with the string module.

Comment: hey @andrew ,how If I want to return the taglist string not the word?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def prefix_match(s, taglist):
    words = s.split()
    return [w for t in taglist for w in words if w.startswith(t)]

s = "This is such an nice artwork"
taglist = ["art", "paint"]
prefix_match(s, taglist)
```

The above will return a list with all the words in the string that match a prefix in the list of tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. I am using `regex`, because I can get rid of punctuation symbols easily this way. Also, I am using `collections.Counter` this might add efficiency if your string has a lot of repeated words.

```
tag_list =  ["art","paint"]

s = "This is such an nice artwork, very nice artwork. This is the best painting I've ever seen"

from collections import Counter
import re

words = re.findall(r'(\w+)', s)

dicto = Counter(words)

def found(s, tag):
    return s.startswith(tag)

words_found = []

for tag in tag_list:
    for k,v in dicto.iteritems():
        if found(k, tag):
            words_found.append((k,v))
```

The last part can be done with list comprehension:

```
words_found = [[(k,v) for k,v in dicto.iteritems() if found(k,tag)] for tag in tag_list]
```

Result:

```
>>> words_found
[('artwork', 2), ('painting', 1)]
```